# Unable to connect to a raspberry pi4 using SSH via Mac

Tags: networking, macos, ubuntu, ssh

So I just set up a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 23.10. I used the OS Customisation options in the Raspberry pi Imager program. There I set SSH to enabled.

I then mounted the SD card after it got verified to my Pi and set it running. Went to my routers interface to grab the IP and then proceeded as follow (replacing IP with my numbers). Opened the terminal on my MacBook. And typed:

```
ssh ubuntu @IP
```

Gives me:

```
ssh: connect to host ubuntu port 22: Connection refused
```

I then went on a google search. Tried:

```
ssh raspberrypi @IP
```

Which gives me:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

That kind of gives me the impression that the SSH service is running. As after checking various usernames I only get the connection refused error with the username `ubuntu`. But I do not know where to go from here. I already formatted the SD card and tried to not use the OS Customisation options and instead manually placed an ssh file without extension. But sadly that also achieved the same results (username ubuntu giving a Connection refusal; everything else giving the other error). I am out of ideas.

Comment: I connect to my own Raspberry PI via RDP and that works very well. I can manage my Pi this way.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your ssh command is including an extra space that shouldn't be there.

The correct command is:

```
ssh ubuntu@YOUR_IP
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to access remote Pi from your MacBook. The simplest command for that is:

```
ssh remote_user_name@remote_ip_address
```

I don't understand, what does the `ubuntu` mean on your command line? Did you add a user named `ubuntu` onto your Pi system somehow? If you are making your first connection into Pi you should use default user/password. If I recall correctly, these are `pi` and `raspberry`, accordingly. In such case, your command line should be

```
ssh pi@IP
```

If you have some other Pi-system with other credential, use their defaults, but basically it is the same.

Comment: That's because, as they mentioned, they installed Ubuntu Desktop, not Raspberry Pi OS. On Ubuntu that's the default username, not `pi`.

Comment: @OliverNybo I have used Ubuntu from version 6.06, I think, but I have never had a user named `ubuntu`... Of course, I never let install to create a default user ;)

Comment: And that is, with no doubt, the best thing to do, but in the Raspberry Pi installer, when selecting Ubuntu, `ubuntu` is the default user. See https://askubuntu.com/q/1199589/916242 ;)